# BigQuery, Joining Comments and Stories in the BigQuery Hacker News dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How are the comments and stories tables related in the HackerNews dataset available on BigQuery, please? It doesn't seem obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Quick example/start-off for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT s.id, c.text
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories` s
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments` c
ON s.id = c.parent
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100
```

You might want to consider using `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` table instead, which is a full daily update of all the stories and comments in Hacker News and has that hierarchy of comment being parent for another comment , etc

[image]

Quick check:

```
SELECT p.text parent, c.text child
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` p
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` c
ON c.parent = p.id 
WHERE c.type = 'comment' AND p.type = 'comment' AND NOT p.text IS NULL
ORDER BY parent
LIMIT 55
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand, if we do it like that, should we have a case where a **comment.parent** refer to another **comment** (for example, an comment of an comment), please?

Answer (score 1):

They join on comments.parent = stories.id

```
SELECT
  s.title, c.*
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments` c,
  `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories` s
WHERE
  c.parent = s.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand, if we do it like that, should we have a case where a **comment.parent** refer to another **comment** (for example, an comment of an comment), please?